# How to click,select and take screenshot of elements or how to perform multiple actions on page and take screenshot in puppeteer?

Tags: backstop.js

I want to interact with drop down list
Scenario:
1) Open the drop down
2) select any one option
I am able to do it with code below is there any way with xpath?

I am able to open the drop down and can click on that but can we achieve this with xpath

```
module.exports = async (page, scenario, vp) => {
console.log('SCENARIO > ' + scenario.label);
await require('../../puppet/clickAndHoverHelper')(page, scenario);
await require('../layout')(page, scenario);
let filterDropdown = await page.$("#SampleFilter .k-widget.k- 
dropdown.cvc-dropdownlist");
await filterDropdown.click();
await page.keyboard.type("small");
```